# Double quatations on value from cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with my code below. It works fine, but doesn't quite do what I want it to.

```
Sub Sum()

 Dim frm As String
 Dim startCell As String
 Dim wb1 As Workbook
 Dim wb2 As Workbook

 Set wb1 = Workbooks("EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm")
 Set wb2 = Workbooks("Låneoversigt.xlsm")

 Set wb1sht = wb1.Worksheets("Facility Overview")
 Set wb2sht = wb2.Worksheets("låneoversigt")

 startCell = Left(wb2sht.Range("A120").Value, 8)
 frm = "=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT('[" & wb1.Name & "]" & wb1sht.Name & "'!G7:G100,8)=" & startCell & ")*('[" & wb1.Name & "]" & wb1sht.Name & "'!AA7:AA100))"

 With wb2sht.Range("DV2")
     .Formula = frm
 End With

End Sub
```

The result of the code is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT('[EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm]Facility Overview'!G7:G100;8)=16908636)*('[EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm]Facility Overview'!AA7:AA100))
```

I need it to put double quations on the value 16908636, as below

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT('[EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm]Facility Overview'!G7:G100;8)="16908636")*('[EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm]Facility Overview'!AA7:AA100))
```

I have tried with """ & startCell & """ but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution :)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT('[EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm]Facility Overview'!G7:G100;8)=LEFT(16908636011;8))*('[EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm]Facility Overview'!AA7:AA100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `"""" & startCell & """" 'use four double quotes`
Like:

```
    =SUMPRODUCT((LEFT('[EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm]Facility Overview'!G7:G100;8)="""" & 16908636 & """")*('[EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm]Facility Overview'!AA7:AA100))
```

Or

Try `Char(34) & startCell & Char(34)`
Like:

```
    =SUMPRODUCT((LEFT('[EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm]Facility Overview'!G7:G100;8)=Char(34) & 16908636 & Char(34))*('[EP_BB_DK_ny.xlsm]Facility Overview'!AA7:AA100))
```

Use which ever method you are comfortable with.

Credits to Stackoverflow.

---